# PrometheusReportingTask reporting metrics only on one processor group

Tags: apache-nifi

I setup PrometheusReportingTask as shown below, however when I cURL the metrics endpoint, I only see metrics for one processor group and the JVM metrics. On the canvas I have several processor groups.

[image]

I have two node cluster running NiFi 1.10.0
Any ideas on what may be happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the JVM metrics to false and restart NiFi.  I noticed mine is "false" and I'm getting full metrics from a cURL (hundreds of lines of metrics).

I haven't tested it, but "Send JVM metrics" might be an either/or thing, not an "in addition to" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to NiFi 1.11 solved my issue.

If for whatever reason, you can't update from 1.10 there is a Jira issue specifying the code change needed to fix the issue.